# AWS Glue - manual data catalog table with partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

My S3 bucket structure is like this -> `s3://input/orders/day=1/sample.csv`

When I run a simple select query on athena, I am able to retrieve data from the data catalog table created using a crawler.

However, if I manually create a data catalog table (by literally copying the schema that I got from running the crawler as mentioned above) and run a simple select on athena I dont get any results.

Below is the JSON schema for reference that crawler has generated and note that this is the same schema I used for creating a data catalog table manually.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "car",
    "Type": "string"
  },
  {
    "Name": "mpg",
    "Type": "double"
  },
  {
    "Name": "cylinders",
    "Type": "bigint"
  },
  {
    "Name": "displacement",
    "Type": "double"
  },
  {
    "Name": "hp",
    "Type": "bigint"
  },
  {
    "Name": "weight",
    "Type": "bigint"
  },
  {
    "Name": "acc",
    "Type": "double"
  },
  {
    "Name": "model",
    "Type": "bigint"
  },
  {
    "Name": "origin",
    "Type": "string"
  },
  {
    "Name": "day",
    "Type": "string",
    "PartitionKey": "Partition (0)"
  }
]
```

I am just trying to explore how to manually create a data catalog table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the partition too in order to be able to query and get the data under the day=1 partition.

This is done by the crawler, crawls the path, identifies the schema of the files, create the corresponding table/s and adds all the partitions that finds.

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to add/create partitions to Glue table via the Glue console, but you have the following options:

- Add Glue Table Partition using Boto 3 SDK. You can use AWS Boto 3 SDK
  to create glue partitions using the batch_create_partition() or
  create_partition() APIs.
- Using Alter Table Add Partition command. You can run the Alter Table
  Add Partition SQL command via Athena to add the partitions manually
  into the table.

Example using alter table:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD PARTITION (day = 1);
```

Please check the data type of your partition and modify accordingly if necessary.

Another practical way is using the following command in Athena:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE `orders`;
```

Repairs the table and adds all the existing partitions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_partition

https://repost.aws/questions/QUQde2PFehR_KSs2C56iGraA/aws-glue-partitions-for-data-catalog-table